# Setting how many samples the boot() function calls

Tags: r

I would like to coerce the boot() function to pull a specific number of samples from the target data set. For example, if the dataset i'm bootstrapping is 100 values, I would like to bootstrap the mean using exactly 50 of those values for each iteration of the bootstrap call. Is this possible? The functionality I'm trying to replicate would look something like this:

```
x = runif(100)
x2 = data.frame()
for (i in 1:100) {
x1 = sample(x,50, replace = TRUE)
x2[i,1] = mean(x1)
}
```

In the end, I'd like to perform somthing like the above function with many different levels of sampling. I'm currently doing something analagous to the above code nested within a for loop but it is VERY slow becaues of the size of the data sets I'm working with so I'm hoping boot() can do it faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ran.gen parameter to `boot` provides a mechanism for doing that. This is a minor modification of the first example in `?boot` that shows how to send a 25-item subsample to the boot-'statistic' function for each replication. Since there are only 49 rows in he `city` dataframe, I passed only 25 items:

```
ratio <- function(d, w) sum(d$x * w)/sum(d$u * w)
boot::boot(city, ratio, R = 999, sim = "parametric",  
                        ran.gen=function(d,p) d[sample(1:49, 25), ])
```

Comment: Sorry if im being daft, the help seems to indicate this is for parametric bootstrapping, whereas the your, and op's example seems like nonparametric (hence ran.gen is ignored??)

Comment: Perhaps it's me that's daft. Can't you use the parametric parameter? The help page says: "Use of sim = "parametric" with a suitable `ran.gen` allows the user to implement any types of nonparametric resampling which are not supported directly."

Comment: I specifically tried to not pass the entire dataset to the statistic-function, since I thought inefficiency was what you were trying to avoid.

Comment: [sorry removed my comment, over second thoughts... added back] hmm, you're right... soi dont know, I've not actually used the argument before, but it seems to be ignored for the nonparametric bs. So im not quite sure how to construct it, but perhaps it is easier to define it in the function..`ratio <- function(d, w, p) {
  d <- d[sample(nrow(d), p), ] ;
  sum(d$x * w)/sum(d$u * w)} ; boot::boot(city, ratio, R = 999, p=10,  stype = "w")`, but i dont know if that would be any faster than doing it in a loop

Comment: Changed the arguments to reflect our discussion.

Comment: thanks. Does the updated code run for you? I get *"Error in statistic(data, ...) : argument "w" is missing, with no default"*, which (i loosely think) is because the index variable, w, is not used in oarametric bs

Comment: @42- I'm very new to writing my own functions in R so I don't understand some bits of the example you posted. In your ratio function, what step of the bootstrapping is generating that argument? And in the ran.gen function, where does the p argument come in? -edit- so I think the w is the index argument that boot generates on it's own, correct? but I'm still not sure about the p in the ran.gen